# Finding median of a trapezoid

Tags: geometry, median

If I have a trapezoid with 2 bases, AD and CF, with base $AD=x+3$ and base $CF=36$, how do I find $x$ and $y$ if their median, $BE$, equals $x+y$?

Ive tried to use $BE=\frac 12(AD+CF)$, but that doesnt give me a numerical answer. And there is a numerical answer. I just cant find HOW to get it/THE WAY of getting it.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Please use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Comment: @Sam T About which trapezoid do you say? $ADCF$ or $ADFC$? What is $y$? Where placed $E$?

Comment: @MichaelRozenberg ADFC, and $B$ is the midpoint of $AC$, and $E$ is the midpoint of $DF $